# MSAL doesn't pop up when project is published to Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

Below is my code to popup and login through MSAL.

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(msal.ClientId)
.WithDefaultRedirectUri()
.WithTenantId(msal.TenantId)
.Build();

var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(msal.Scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

Code above works when it's running on my local machine.

And below is my settings in Azure AD. Its working when I set it to localhost:5000
[image]

But when I set the localhost to 'myWebAppUrl' which is hosted on Azure Virtual Machine. MSAL won't popup. And it will just return "The operation was cancelled". Anything I missed here?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can use http://myWebAppUrl but not the https here? It may not relate to the issue itself...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below points.

1. In azure ad,the reply URL must begin with the scheme https, unless using localhost. ex`:http://localhost:5000`
   Else you can use something like `https://yourappurl`  and don’t forget to Grant admin consent
   Under Permissions for the scopes you have in azure ad.
   Please check [Redirect URI restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)
2. Apps that use system browsers: `http://localhost`

   Apps that use embedded
   browsers:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`

   For Node.js, you can use `msal://redirect`

Please check [Add a redirect URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-redirect-uri) section and [Client application configuration (MSAL)  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri-for-public-client-apps)
And check if you can use confidential client to your app
.

> Some authentication libraries like MSAL.NET use a default value of
> urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob when no other redirect URI is specified,
> which is not recommended. This default will be updated as a breaking
> change in the next major release.

Other references

1. [Instantiate a public client app (MSAL.NET) - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-instantiate-public-client-config-options#default-reply-uri)
2. [Initialize MSAL.NET client applications - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications#initializing-a-public-client-application-from-configuration-options)